# Gröbner basis of $f=x^2 y +xy^2 +y^2 $, $f_1 =y^2 -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis

Consider the following polynomials:

$$f=x^2 y +xy^2 +y^2; \qquad f_1 =y^2 -1; \quad\text{and}\quad f_2 = xy -1. $$

Dividing by $(f_1,f_2)$, one gets

$$f=f_1 (x+1)+f_2 (x)+2x+1. $$

During lecture the teacher found a Gröbner basis by multiplying 3 matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 &-1& -y \\ 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -1 &0 \\ 0& 1\\ y& -x\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} xy -1\\ y^2-1\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ y^2-1\\ x-y \end{bmatrix} $$

This is supposed to be a Gröbner basis but I'm not sure how it was obtained through matrix multiplication.

This is an example from Cox, Little, and O'Shea's, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*, chapter 2, section 3, example 4.

Comment: link to a picture that is oversize https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwTs0-B1cYOaEd2RTBVQkJsWkU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have here a case where the Buchberger algorithm is cast into a linear algebra system. It is especially applied to a system of two polynomials. So, what do these matrices represent? The second matrix transforms a set of two equations to a set of three; one with changed sign: $-f_2$, one identical $f_1$  and a new one as combination $\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2$. Whence the following setup:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f_2 \\f_1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -f_2\\ f_1 \\ \alpha f_1 + \beta f_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are determined by the Buchbeger algorithm and construct a so-called *$S$-polynomial*. More details [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Buchberger_algorithm#Buchberger.27s_Algorithm). The $S$-polynomial is defined by (as done in the link): $$\operatorname{SPOL}(f_1,f_2) = \frac{\operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LT}(f_1),\operatorname{LT}(f_2))}{\operatorname{LM}(f_1)}f_1-\frac{\operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LT}(f_1),\operatorname{LT}(f_2))}{\operatorname{LM}(f_2)}f_2,$$ where $\operatorname{LCM}$ means the least common multiple, $\operatorname{LT}(f)$ the leading term of $f$ and $\operatorname{LM}(f)$ the leading monomial of $f$. This gives us the following values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$: $$\alpha = \frac{\operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LT}(f_1),\operatorname{LT}(f_2))}{\operatorname{LM}(f_1)},\ \beta = -\frac{\operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LT}(f_1),\operatorname{LT}(f_2))}{\operatorname{LM}(f_2)}.$$ So in the example of the question $\alpha = \frac{xy^2}{y^2} = x$ and $\beta = -\frac{xy^2}{xy}=-y$. Now $$\operatorname{SPOL}(f_1,f_2) = \alpha f_1 + \beta f_2 = x(y^2-1) - y(xy-1) = y - x = -\operatorname{SPOL}(f_2,f_1),$$
so the product of the last two matrices gives us: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -f_1 \\ f_2 \\ \operatorname{SPOL}(f_2,f_1) \end{pmatrix}  .$$
The significance of the first matrix is the decision which of the two original polynomials remains and which will be replaced by $0$. Let us call our new element of the Gröbner basis $f_3 $ and let's calculate $\operatorname{SPOL}(f_2,f_3) = \frac{xy}{xy}(xy-1)-\frac{xy}{x}(x-y)=y^2-1 = f_1$. Hence the first row in the first matrix. This proves that if we omit $f_2$ the remaining polynomials form a Gröbner basis. If on the other hand we calculate $\operatorname{SPOL}(f_1,f_3) = -f_3$ so nothing new. The result is that we have obtained a Gröbner basis simply by multiplying matrices.