# A rank puzzle, or finding the implicit form of a Bézier curve without resultants

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra, bezier-curve

I've recently [completely reworked](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Kinross/commit/d28a713bf719616d70224fe2e08ffec305f1f7fe) the code in my [Kinross](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Kinross) library that finds the intersection of Bézier curves. I've come a long way from first [developing my own method and asking for better ones](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2550987/357390), then developing another method based on [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2551044/357390) I got there. The Bézier curves and almost all computations (arithmetic, root-finding, etc.) now handle polynomials only in the Bernstein basis, not the less stable power basis. Most of the techniques implemented are from Sederberg's [*Computer Aided Geometric Design*](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1) (CAGD).

The new approach to curve intersection in Kinross is through implicitisation and [curve inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527005/357390), both described in detail in CAGD. However, the book has a section describing how to invert curves using a nullspace computation (on p. 205), while its sections on implicitisation only describe how to obtain the implicit form of a Bézier curve using resultants (in particular determinants of matrices of polynomials, which NumPy doesn't support). I found a way to implicitise Bézier curves using little more than another nullspace computation, and the question here is asking why that method works.

---

The implicitisation task is this: given a Bézier curve $(x(t),y(t))$, find a polynomial $f(x,y)=0$ describing points on the (infinitely extended) curve. Since the curve has a known degree, the set of terms of $f$ that could possibly be non-zero is finite and known. For the common cubic curve, $f$ has the following form:
$$c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3x^2+c_4xy+c_5y^2+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+c_8xy^2+c_9y^3=0$$
All the monomials $x,y,x^3,y^3,\dots$ are themselves polynomials in $t$, and all can be computed in the Bernstein basis at a common degree using techniques described in CAGD. Thus I can write a linear system for $f$:
$$\mathbf{Zc}=\begin{bmatrix}\bf1&\bf x&\bf y&\bf x^2&\bf xy&\bf y^2&\bf x^3&\bf x^2y&\bf xy^2&\bf y^3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\\c_5\\c_6\\c_7\\c_8\\c_9\end{bmatrix}=\bf 0$$
Each boldface entry is a length-$10$ column vector $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{9})^T$ of Bernstein basis coefficients representing the corresponding monomial $t$-polynomial, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(1-t)^{n-k}t^ka_k$. $\bf xy^2$ represents $x(t)y(t)^2$ and so on.

The $n+1$ Bernstein basis polynomials of degree $n$ form a basis for the vector space of all polynomials with degree at most $n$. Thus, if $\mathbf c\ne\mathbf 0$ satisfies $\mathbf{Zc}=\mathbf0$, it will contain a correct set of coefficients for $f$.

What puzzles me is that *$\bf Z$ always seems to be rank-deficient* despite being a square matrix (in the cubic case), so a non-zero solution $\mathbf c$ can always be found (via QR decomposition among other means) and $f$ calculated – all without resorting to resultants.

> Why is $\bf Z$ as I have constructed it, from the parametric polynomials $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, always rank-deficient?

My first guess was that the deficiency arises from the resultant's existence, but that argument feels unrigorous. Note that the columns of $\bf Z$ can be converted to and from the power basis by left-multiplying by appropriate invertible matrices, which may make the answer simpler.

*I am asking this question to commemorate my reaching of $50000$ reputation.*

Comment: Going a bit out on a limb here but isn't this a consequence from the fact that most cubic algebraic curves cannot be rationally parameterized? In other words, your Bezier curve (rational or not) will only span a small subset of all algebraic curves. I think this fact will manifest itself in a rank deficient matrix in your case.